# How to set dynamic x-axis title in power bi while doing drill down?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

By default, the graph is showing "Division" wise data and the a-axis title is "Division".On drill down, I am showing "Department" wise data.
The expected x-axis title is "Department" but it's showing the "Division Department".How to fix this?
Please refer to the attached images for clarity.
[image: Before drill down]

[image: Fields]

[image: After drill down]

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off the 'Concatenate Labels' option the in X-axis format setting.
[image]

This will now should only the relevant level in the hierarchy

Comment: After changing this, If I choose  "Go to the next level in the hierarchy" it showing "Department" but while drill down it's showing "division department" as before.